# Unable to connect to collator using rpc

Tags: polkadot, parachain-collator

I'm running a few collators for a parachain connected to polkadot, but after they've been running for sometime we stop being able to connect using rpc, we are using `polkadot v1.3.0`, does anyone know what could be the issue?
I thought it could be related to the hardware specs of the nodes they are running on, but I've upgraded the instances they are running on to `c6id.2xlarge` and the issue persists. The collators keep producing blocks without any issues.

Update:

I can not see any errors in the collator logs, the error I get from the polkadotjs app is `1006:: Abnormal Closure`

The command used to start the collator is:
`./target/release/parachain --collator --base-path /tmp/chain-170223/collator-data/ --port 40333 --rpc-port 9946 --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --chain ./chain-spec-raw-170223.json --  --execution wasm  --base-path /tmp/chain-170223/relay-data/ --chain ./resources/polkadot.json --port 30333 --rpc-port 9944 --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --wasm-execution Compiled --pruning 1000`

Thanks.

Comment: Any error message or just not receiving response?

Comment: I've updated the post describing the error message

Comment: What's your boot command?

Comment: I've updated the post with the command

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error using PolkadotJS UI in the browser can be because something is blocking the connection for example uBlock. See this issue: [FATAL: Unable to initialize the API: disconnected from wss://pub.elara.patract.io/kusama: 1006:: Abnormal Closure #3960](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/3960)

You can try the curl command in your terminal to see if you have the same error:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "rpc_methods"}' your-rpc-endpoint
```

Other checks you can do in the browser are the follow [Polkadot-JS UI: How to Troubleshoot Connection Issues](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000176918-polkadot-js-ui-how-to-troubleshoot-connection-issues)

Comment: Thanks! But why would it be that I'm able to connect at first? it is only after the collator has been running for some time that I have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be solved now, the fix was to increase the amount of rpc connections allowed by the node, using the `--rpc-max-connections` flag.